# Weird behaviour when using querySelector

Tags: javascript

As my understanding, when using `element.querySelector()`, the query should be start on particular element.

However, when I run using code below, it keep selected the first `DIV` tag in particular element.

```js
const rootDiv = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(rootDiv.querySelector('div').innerHTML);
console.log(rootDiv.querySelector('div > div').innerHTML);
console.log(rootDiv.querySelector('div > div > div').innerHTML);
console.log(rootDiv.querySelector('div > div > div > div').innerHTML);
console.log(rootDiv.querySelector('div > div > div > div > div').innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div id="test">
      <div>
        <div>
        This is content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the first few results is the same.
This this a bug? Or it will query from start of the document?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What `querySelector` does is it finds an element *somewhere in the document* that matches the CSS selector passed, and *then* checks that the found element is a descendant of the element you called `querySelector` on. It doesn't start at the element it was called on and search downwards - rather, it always starts at the document level, looks for elements that match the selector, and checks that the element is also a descendant of the calling context element. It's a bit unintuitive.

So:

```
someElement.querySelector(selectorStr)
```

is like

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(selectorStr)]
  .find(elm => someElement.contains(elm));
```

A possible solution is to use `:scope` to indicate that you want the selection to start at the `rootDiv`, rather than at `document`:

```js
const rootDiv = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(rootDiv.querySelector(':scope > div').innerHTML);
console.log(rootDiv.querySelector(':scope > div > div').innerHTML);
console.log(rootDiv.querySelector(':scope > div > div > div').innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div id="test">
      <div>
        <div>
        This is content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`:scope` is supported in all modern browsers but Edge.

Comment: `:scope` is not supported by all but most of the major browsers. Anyways, thank for explanation and this should be the answer. Thanks.

Comment: `:scope` doesn't work with IE and Edge, I think it's important to point this out

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#Browser_compatibility) is the browser compatibility table - we have to resist just few months more since Edge is implementing Chromium engine :P

Comment: Do you have any sources for the browser engine actually working this way ? - The query would have the same result, if the engine would start with the first div and check if it matches the query selector...

Answer (score 7):

The currently accepted answer somehow provides a valid logical explanation as to what happens, but they are factually wrong.

`Element.querySelector` triggers the [*match a selector against tree*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#match-a-selector-against-a-tree) algorithm, which goes **from the root element** and checks if its descendants **do match the selector**.

The selector itself is absolute, it doesn't have any knowledge of a Document and doesn't even require that your Element be appended to any. And apart from the `:scope` attribute, it doesn't either care with which *root* you called the `querySelector` method.

If we wanted to rewrite it ourselves, it would be more like

```
const walker = document.createTreeWalker(element, {
  NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
  { acceptNode: (node) => return node.matches(selector) && NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT }
});
return walker.nextNode();
```

```js
const rootDiv = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(querySelector(rootDiv, 'div>div').innerHTML);

function querySelector(element, selector) {
  const walker = document.createTreeWalker(element, 
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    {
      acceptNode: (node) => node.matches(selector) && NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
    });
  return walker.nextNode();
};
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div id="test">
      <div>
        <div>
          This is content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the big difference that this implementation doesn't support the special [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) selector.

You may think it's the same going from the document or going from the root element, but not only will it make a difference in terms of performances, it will also allow for using this method while the element is not appended to any document.

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="test"><div class="bar"></div></div>')

console.log(div.querySelector('div>.bar')); // found
console.log(document.querySelector('div>.bar')); // null
```

In the same way, matching elements in the Shadow-DOM would not be possible if we only had Document.querySelector.

Comment: Goood explanaition - especially the bit about Nodes not part of the document. This represents more clearly what the browser engine actually does.

Answer (score 1):

The query selector `div > div > div` only means:

**Find a div which has a parent and a granparent which are both also a div.**

And if you start with the first child of *test* and check the selector, it is true. And this is the reason why only your last query selects the innermost div, since it has the first predicate (find a div with a great-great-grandparent-div) which is not fulfilled by the first child of *test*.

The query-selector will only test descendants, but it will evaluate the expression in scope of the whole document. Just imagine a selector like checking properties of an element - even if you only view the child element, it is still the child of its parent.